# jQuery selectors select 2nd cell of 2nd row of 2nd table of a form with specific action attrib

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<form action="blah">
  <table>...</table>
  <table>
     <tr>...</tr>
     <tr>  
         <td>...<td>
         <td> **some text that changes** </td>
```

Given the above html structure, how do i get the  text that changes , using jQuery

So i want jquery to search like this:
-look for form that has atrribute action="blah"
-select the 2nd table of the form
-select the 2nd row (tr) of the table
-select the 2nd cell (td) of the row
-give me the text

This will help me greatly understanding jquery... i'm new to it.

Something like $('form[action="blah"]').tables(2).rows(2).cells(2).text     but this is not a valid jquery match

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you want the second table cell in the second table row of the second table?  The `eq` function can make this easy

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ju79Y/)

```
var text = $("table:eq(1) tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text();
```

Also note that you didn't close this table cell correctly:

```
<td>...<td>
```

should be

```
<td>...</td>
```

**EDIT**

If there are other tables on the page, and you want to make sure you get the second on *in the form*, then add the form to your selector:

```
var text = $("form[action='blah'] table:eq(1) tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text();
```

Comment: table elements don't need to be closed

Comment: @Sinetheta - are you sure?  My fiddle didn't work right until I closed that `td`

Comment: Well...it's not the 2nd table on the page...  it's the 2nd table in the FORM element.

I know i can get the form with 
$('form[action="blah"]')

Comment: @Sinetheta - interesting.  I didn't know you could get away with not closing td's and tr's.

Comment: @adam > thank you so much

My actual html is way more complex (more than 2 tables,etc..)  but i used your example to understand how to make my own.
This code does what i wanted :
  var text = $('form[action="blah"] table:eq(0) tr:eq(1) td:eq(2) table:eq(0) tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) ').text();

Comment: @tintino - glad to hear it.  Good luck!

Comment: @AdamRackis if tintino has accepted your answer maybe update the selector to one which targets the form, as per the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
To select second element use `eq(1)`.
Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ajinkya_Parakh/VSKhG/).

Answer (score 2):

Target then drill down with find. Adam had the right idea. You just want to avoid making one giant selector. It's a trade-off between readability and speed.

If you want to optimize fully then feel free to make each step down with a find(). But unless this selector is being evaluated repeatedly it shouldn't matter.

```
$('form[action="blah"]').find("table:eq(1) tr:eq(1) td:eq(1)").text();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ju79Y/4/)